# how to achieve *SMOOTH* fade in and out animation on mobile with jquery and css3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I know that I can fade in and out with jquery, but on mobile it will be jittery and like low fps or something. After a lot of searching I've found out I can use css3 transition to go to opacitiy 0, but the problem is the element will still have the place to itself. even with visibility:none, it will keep the space it was in. the only way is to use display:none but as I know I can't animate that.
So is there a way to achieve smooth fade in and out animation on mobile with a combination of jquery and css3? or even just one? Thank you.

`**EDIT**`: Okay the answer for fadeout is working pretty well, now a fade in would be sweet. the problem is I think I have to pul a millisecond delay after `('#id').css('display','block')` and before `('#id').css('opactity','1')`. don't if it is efficient and all. but it works that way but all my other animations wouldn't work. still am really confused.

Comment: you can't animate display property, but for example you can animate height property

Comment: JQuery animations shouldn't be jittery on mobile (AFAIK). You probably have a slow mobile device.

Comment: You could add two classes - one which has a `transition` time of say 1s which changes opacity to 0, then the other class which has a `transition-delay` of 1s which moves the element off canvas e.g. `left: -9999px`

Comment: @JonathanLam Well I'm testing on iPhone 6 plus. I think it should be able to handle it. and btw the css3 animations are working fine but jquery fadeIn() is not.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney well I think that will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should always try and use CSS3 transitions, instead of jQuery animations. Here I use a CSS3 transition to fade out the `.square`, and then I wait until the transition has ended to set the `display` to `none`.

If you animate an element in jQuery, for example, using `fadeOut`, you'll see what happens. It basically sets the opacity to 1, and then brings that value down to 0 in tiny increments. This is very inefficient. So it's better to always use CSS3 transitions and animations wherever possible.

Fade out: https://jsfiddle.net/danhaswings/znLL0ws5/1/

Fade in: https://jsfiddle.net/danhaswings/kjgmxa8x/

**HTML**

```
<div class="square"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.square {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var $square = $('.square');

$square.css('opacity', '0');

$square.one("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend", function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: I think this is what I need. I'll try that and get back to you.

Comment: I think this fiddle shows your work better I'm gonna try that, I think I've found my answer  https://jsfiddle.net/znLL0ws5/2/

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, can you provide a way for the otherway around? I mean fading in?

Comment: Well It's working like a charm Thank you very much. If you could answer the above question whenever you could, I'd be happy.

Comment: Sure, let me make a fiddle.

Comment: Awesome. Works like a charm on webkit apps. Here is a fiddle with both fade in and out https://jsfiddle.net/wizajay/wdwn5kcx/

Comment: I know it's an oldie, but thought I'd add, there's no need to set a small timeout period. In your fiddle example you've set 50 as your period. You can set this to 0 and it will work fine... still pushing the code within to the back of the queue and allowing the browser to repaint the "display: block" code before it.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Shouldn't we define .one first, which is as I understand it the transition callback, then make the transition call itself, which is setting opacity?
Both version work here, because as the transition starts the callback is being set immediately.

Answer (score 5):

What sort of phone are you testing on to get such slow / jittery animations? Mine seems to work fine for all of the animations that are supported on mobile browsers.

In any case, you can always try to use css keyframes.

Annoyingly, you cannot animate certain attributes (such as `display`) but it does allow for quite a lot of things including opacity as shown below.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 20px;
}
.to_hide {
  -webkit-animation: hide 5s forwards;
  animation: hide 2s forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes hide {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="to_hide"></div>
<div></div>
```

- [Keyframes on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes)

---

Ultimately, on mobiles you should try to avoid using animations as mobile browsers are not optimized for such things. Your website should degrade gracefully in both size, layout, content and also animations.

Comment: This still leaves the element in place, taking up space, therefore you'll have a gap - as your example shows

Comment: Well I'm testing on iphone6 plus. but the jquery fade animation is pretty slow on it.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I did make a note of that in my answer, but there are very little other alternatives without using JS

Comment: change `hide 5s` to `hide 1s` - this controls fade speed

Comment: @ArmanMomeni try out the CSS alternative and see how it goes. The problem really lies in how to remove its ability to get in the way of things.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney adding position absolute should fix the issue you relate to as shown above.

Comment: @ArmanMomeni fixed up my answer and shouldnt effect the elements around it once hidden.

Comment: @Stewartside Yeah that's great, I'd still probably add `left: -9999px` or something to the end keyframe to be sure it's gone - great solution!

Answer (score -1):

Should go smoothly if you use jQuery's `fadeIn()`, which will fade in an element with
`display: none`

```
$element.fadeIn();
```

---

```js
function show() {
  $("#el").fadeIn();
}
```

```css
#el {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="show()">Show</button>
<div id="el">Hello</div>
```

Comment: It works but the problem is the fps is really really low. although the css animations like loadings are fine.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)

> You should always look to avoid animating properties that will trigger layout or paints, both of which are expensive and may lead to skipped frames.

You should be able to achieve a fade transition combining the opacity and transform properties

Comment: Doesn't explain how to achieve the desired result.

Comment: @DanielDewhurst -- true, I just posted an article as reference doc to achieve *smooth* (light weight) animations. I'm not good to CSS but i wanted to share this interesting article I saw time ago